# How to download a folder from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I want to download this folder to my computer.

Can you show me how to download the complete folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The owner of that folder has prevented viewers from downloading the items.

[image: Sharing settings]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can download this folder or download any video as the owner of the video has restricted the user to download them.

But you can do i think but it will take time. You use any Screen recorder and record them easily. I know looks like really stupid but yes it works...

Please reply if it helps! :)